# .Net Thread vs ThreadPool vs Task for SerialPort Communication

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool, task

I've run into an interesting problem in my C# .Net 4.0 application using the `SerialPort` class and either `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `Task`s.

The problem only occurs if I use 2 or more SerialPorts simultaneously.  Each serial port runs in its own thread that I create in 1 of 3 ways:

1. `new Thread(DoSerialCommX)`
2. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSerialCommX)`
3. `new Task(DoSerialCommX, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start()`

To illustrate the problem, I created my `DoSerialCommX` method to read and write to the serial port forever in a loop. It looks something like this:  (I'm not actually doing this in my real program.  This is just a snippet from my test program that isolates and illustrates the problem).

```
private void DoSerialCommX()
{
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("ComX", 9600);
    port.Open();

    while(true)
    {
        //Read and write to serial port
    }
}
```

If I use either method 2 or 3, the serial communication stutters and I receive many communication timeouts.  If I use method 1, all is good.  Also, I should mention this only seems to occur on my Intel Atom based PCs.  Desktop PC's seem to have no problems.

I know the thread pool reuses threads, and by default `Task` uses the thread pool.  And I know that the thread pool really intended for short-lived operations.  But I tried using the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, which I thought would spawn a dedicated thread rather than use the thread pool, but it still didn't work.

**So the Question:**  What makes `Thread` so special in this situation?  Is there something about `Thread` that makes it better suited for IO operations?

**Edit:**
The answers so far seem to assume that I am trying to use the ThreadPool or Tasks for a never-ending process.  In my real application this is not the case.  I'm only using a never-ending loop in the code above to illustrate the problem.  I really need to know why `Thread` works and `ThreadPool` and `Task` don't.  What is technically different about them that would cause the serial communication to hiccup?

Comment: I suppose it's a silly question, but you're not trying to manage >= 25 threads, are you?

Comment: @JeffN825, no, there is only 1 thread per serial port, and I'm using at most 4 serial ports.

Comment: This is not actually a CPU-intensive loop, right?  I mean, the reading blocks on the serial port, yes?

Comment: Tasks may look the same as Threads Hans - ultimately resulting in a thread getting bound for execution, but the route it takes is via a seperate Task Scheduler independent of the OS thread scheduler.  More baggage and burden, more code to run.

Comment: @stephbu - the task scheduler is not independent of the OS thread scheduler.  The pool threads that run the tasks are kernel threads that extract tasks from queues and run them.  It is almost beyond belief that a 9600-baud serial port should be an issue for either the threadpool or a dedicated thread.  There is something funny going on with either the OP code, OP driver or OP hardware.

Comment: Martin - the Windows threads scheduler is completely oblivious to the existence of the .NET Tasks TaskScheduler .  Its absolutely conceivable that other threads in the pool will preempt your thread when they run at the same priority, and you engage in blocking IO.  Look at a basic console application and you'll notice 10's of threads running at the same priority.  Adding any threadpool isn't going to make that better.

Comment: 'Windows threads scheduler is completely oblivious to the existence of the .NET Tasks TaskScheduler' yes, I agree, but not the other way round.  I think we actually agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Philosophically there is little difference between 1, 2 and 3 in how executing thread behaves.  They all share the same default execution priority unless you override it - notionally the thread scheduler would use the same strategy to schedule them.  They'd all sit happily spinning in the loop.

I suspect the bigger difference between methods is:

1. infrastructure cost (threads, memory etc.) spun up to support threadpool of #2 and #3 all of which will contend for clock timeslices with your execution loop.
2. thread context switching cost on the less-muscular Atom. The Atom has a smaller caches, 
   and shorter processing pipeline(s).  More running threads = more context switches, more dumping of pipeline(s) and reduced instruction cache efficiency.

From a functional point of view use of Method 2 and 3 are somewhat abusive - your intention is to never exit the method.  These strategies are optimized for atomic, finite operations, and somewhat unguided execution oft suited for IO Completion port tasks such as async network, disk operations etc...  (Maybe a possibility for your serial port code too?)

I would skip 2 & 3 unless you're interested in adapting to Async IO.  Focus on thread - seems like you're wanting finer grain, predictable execution control without the infrastructure overhead that Threadpool brings.

Comment: It's a 9600-baud serial port!  One character every millisecond.  The UART has a hardware buffer, the driver has a buffer.  It is almost beyond belief that either of these two points could be an issue here.

Comment: My Asus atomic-powered laptop, (!), will happily run two serial ports at 115Kbaud without problems.  It's not the hardware in general, (though, of course, the OP's box may be bad).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this happens BECAUSE you are reading/writing from a COM port.  Without that factor all of these should perform identically because (if you check) they are all running in a thread with Normal priority.

Maybe read up on [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the thread pool to see if that could explain this odd behavior.

Comment: I think you are exactly right.  The serial port is a key component of this problem.  Could you maybe elaborate on the I/O completion port suggestion?

Comment: See also http://hi.baidu.com/jrckkyy/blog/item/401422527c131b070df3e37b.html for more information on how I/O Completion ports work.

Answer (score 1):

There is something off with either your code, your driver or your hardware that has put your serial port performance so 'on the edge' that it is on the verge of not working all the time.  There should be no problem using a dedicated thread or the threadpool, (mod. using up a threadpool thread to block on a serial port read).

Two 9600-baud serial ports you can run with an abacus, providing the beads and wires are well oiled.

Comment: Puh. I can easily run two 9600-baud serial ports on a rusty abacus.

Comment: That's OK for you.  You probably have a multiwired abacus with hyperBeads.

Answer (score 0):

There are slight differences - which caused the timeouts:

- Using Thread explicitly creates a new thread when Thread.Start() is
  called - and it ensures that your code runs that specific moment.
- Using ThreadPool ensures that a thread would be opened in the near
  future according to internal ThreadPool logic. Because ThreadPool
  number is limited it's advisable ot to use it for long (or infinite)
  running operations.
- Using task would only determine that the code would run. Either on
  another thread or even on the main thread and does not ensure that it
  would run immediately or that different tasks would run on different
  threads.

And so if you want your task to start quickly always use Thread. Both Tasks and ThreadPool has some additional "infrastructure overhead" that might cause the slight delays you noticed.

Since both ThreadPool and task are not meant to be used when your task never exist I suggest you use Thread.